# My matlab code doesnt work but i dont know why?

Tags: matlab

I have tried to run this matlab code :

```
t = 0:1e-10:1e-3;
F=2.335807205111373e+16;
Y=cosh(t*F);
plot(t,Y), grid on
```

I didn't have plot ?? also result for Y is infinity ?

Where is the problem on my code ??

Comment: How is `delta` defined?

Comment: First, do you mean `plot(t,Y)`?

Comment: Second, are you sure you want to use the hyperbolic cosine `cosh` instead of `cos`?

Comment: Third, the sampling frequency is 1e10, while the cosine is 2e16. Hence, you are violating the Nyquist Theorem.

Comment: Fourth, maybe the cosine argument is `2*pi*F*t`?

Comment: yes I am sure I need cosh

Comment: @tashuhka. How exactly are you violating Nyquist? I am not sure your comment makes sense.

Comment: @MadPhysicist. In case, the user meant `cos` instead of `cosh`, he is totally violating Nyquist.

Comment: yes I am sure I need {cosh} not {cos}

Comment: Could you share us the formula you are trying to implement?

Comment: @tashuhka. Fair enough. But I doubt it is affecting the plot in any way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can implement this equation and it will work for you:

[image]

I tried to use above formula and got these results:

```
>> (1 + exp(-2*900))/(2*exp(-900))

ans =

   Inf

>> (1 + exp(-2*700))/(2*exp(-700))

ans =

  5.0712e+303
```

Answer (score 3):

The maximum value for a double is 1.7e308.
This value is reached when you do the following in Matlab

```
K>> cosh(710)

ans =

  1.1170e+308

K>> cosh(711)

ans =

   Inf
```

So, the maximum value you can feed to cosh appears to be 710. The numbers you are using appear to be too high, except for the first one which is 0.

Comment: The numbers you are using are too high for the standard types in Matlab. (1) You can use variable-precision arithmetic, which is possible when using the Symbolic Math Toolbox. (2) Maybe you can try the [vpi toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725). (3) Or you have to try to reach your goal in a different way. Adjust your formulas and try other ways to get around it.